# DataSource occupying lot of heap space

Tags: jboss

In our application , we are using data source configured with JBoss. Recently we found it is occupying lot of heap space around 600 MB. In some places in our classes we are storing the value of the data source in some transient variables.

It is instance of '**Org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrapperDataSource**'.

This problem we are getting only for a particular client environments.

Any idea how to resolve or find out the cause?

Answer (score 0):

Are your properly cleaning up database connections in your application? If you aren't that could be retaining datasource resources.

Comment: Are the connections created from the data source stored as part of the datasource in JVM